# How Can I Use Generics to Write a Reusuable TSV Parser in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to implement a function `parseTSV()` that parses a TSV file and returns an array of objects but I am having a hard time figuring out how to type the function.

This is what I have so far:

```js
export const parseTsv = <T>(tsvFilepath: string) => {
    const tsv = fs.readFileSync(tsvFilepath, 'utf8');
    const lines = tsv.split('\n');
    const result: T[] = [];
    const columns = lines[0].split('\t'); // How can I constrain columns to be a key of T?

    for (let i = 2; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const obj = {} as T;
        const currentline = lines[i].split("\t");

        for (let j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
            obj[columns[j]] = currentline[j]; /* ERROR: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'. */
        }

        result.push(obj);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I wrote the function with intending for the caller to define `<T>` which is the interface of the object parsed from the TSV file (i.e., the columns in the TSV file).

Comment: That call signature cannot be implemented safely (e.g., I could call `parseTsv<{a: string}>(path)` and `parseTsv<{a: number}>(path)` with the same `path`, and both compile to `parseTsv(path)` at runtime, so the output cannot be both a `{a: string}` and a `{a: number}`); so if you want that call signature you might as well use `any` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrDlzW).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what specifically is missing?

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your answer! This is one approach but I was really hoping to implement the function with type safety. Is it impossible to achieve type safety in this situation because we have no control over the content of the file (i.e. the program does not know what columns will be present in the file)?

Comment: Right; the program reads a file and then produces an array of objects with some string keys and some string values... that is, `{[k: string]: string}[]`. Claiming it's some more specific type is not necessarily safe.  If you're okay with returning `{[k: string]: string}[]`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mM8ebN), then the compiler will be happy with it, but then the user will need to either write `as T[]` for whatever `T` they want and everything will be fine *if they are right about `T`*, or you'll need some kind of runtime schema validation code.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I should write up an answer or if I'm missing something about the question.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Let's say the user passes an interface `Foo {bar: string, baz: string}` as the generic. I want this function to parse the TSV file and throw an error if the columns do not match the generic the user passed. Otherwise, proceed with parsing the TSV file and returning the objects (which we now know conform to the interface the user passed). I think you are right that maybe I need to use some form of runtime type constraint. What would that look like?

Comment: You could pass in a list of the expected keys and then do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPzYLN), which is about as type safe as I can think to make it (although I'm using type assertions and taking on some of the type safety guarantees myself). Is that what you're looking for?  Note that the scope of your question seems to be drifting away from "how to type the function" toward "how to implement the function".  I'm trying to pin the question down so it can be answered, and right now it's moving. Could you [edit] the question to ask exactly what you want to see answered?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! I was trying to find a way to extract the headers from the type and assert against the extracted headers to make sure they match the passed type. I don't think there is a way to get an array of strings from the passed generic type so the closest thing is to pass the headers in as a param.

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance (probably not for a while because it is now bedtime in my time zone)

Comment: Note that unless your TSV files have a blank line after the header, your implementation will skip the first line of object data.  I've fixed that in my code but you might want to fix that in the question also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call signature

```
declare const parseTsv: <T>(tsvFilepath: string) => T[]
```

cannot be safely implemented.  It claims to take a `tsvFilepath` string and produce an array of values of type `T` supplied by the caller at design time.  But the static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TS is compiled to JS, and `T` is just a design-time type, not a runtime value.  No information about `T` is available to the function that runs, and so if it does work it would be a coincidence; you'd be relying on the *developer* to verify that the type being returned will be correct.

Consider the following TypeScript code:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
    baz: string;
}
const foos: Foo[] = parseTsv<Foo>("somePath");
foos.map(x => x.bar.toUpperCase());

interface EvilFoo {
    bar: number;
    baz: string;
}
const evils: EvilFoo[] = parseTsv<EvilFoo>("somePath");
evils.map(x => x.bar.toFixed());
```

At runtime that will almost certainly be

```
const foos = parseTsv("somePath");
foos.map(x => x.bar.toUpperCase());
const evils = parseTsv("somePath");
evils.map(x => x.bar.toFixed());
```

where `parseTsv("somePath")` is run twice, with the same input, and I think it's safe to assume that they will return the same output.  Nothing about `Foo` or `EvilFoo` is involved.  The chance that the file at `"somePath"` represents *both* an array of `Foo` objects *and* an array of `EvilFoo` objects is quite low (an object with both a `string` and a `number` at the `bar` property is not possible), so it is very likely that at least one of those `map()` methods will try to dereference `undefined` and you'll get a runtime error.

Indeed your implementation of `parseTsv()` can't even produce a type with non-`string` properties, while `T` is completely unconstrained.  But even if we [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to only have `string` properties, the function doesn't know what keys it can expect.  The only safe way to give your `parseTsv()` a call signature would be something like the non-generic:

```
declare const parseTsv: (tsvFilepath: string) => {[k: string]: string | undefined}[]
```

which says that the output will be an array of some objects whose properties are either `string` or `undefined`.

---

If you want to keep your implementation the same at runtime and your typing the same, then I wouldn't worry much about type safety in the implementation; just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to avoid warnings:

```
export const parseTsv = <T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(
    tsvFilepath: string) => {
    const tsv = fs.readFileSync(tsvFilepath, 'utf8');
    const lines = tsv.split('\n');
    const result: T[] = [];
    const columns = lines[0].split('\t');
    for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const obj = {} as any; // just use any
        const currentline = lines[i].split("\t");
        for (let j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
            obj[columns[j]] = currentline[j];
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

If you want something more type safe, you'll need to change your call signature and the implementation.  One possible approach could be:

```
const parseTsv = <K extends string>(tsvFilepath: string, ...keys: K[]) => {
    const tsv = fs.readFileSync(tsvFilepath, 'utf8');
    const lines = tsv.split('\n');
    const result: { [P in K]: string }[] = [];
    if (!lines.length) return result;
    const columns = lines[0].split('\t') as K[];
    for (const key of keys) {
        if (!columns.includes(key)) throw new Error(
            "TSV file is missing expected header named \"" +
            key + "\" in line 1"
        );
    }
    for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
        const obj = {} as { [P in K]: string };
        const currentline = lines[i].split("\t");
        for (let j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
            const key = columns[j];
            const val = currentline[j];
            if (typeof val !== "string") throw new Error(
                "TSV file is missing expected value for \"" +
                key + "\" in line " + (i + 1)
            );
            obj[key] = currentline[j];
        }
        result.push(obj);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here you are passing in the list of `keys` you expect to exist on your objects. The function is generic only in the type `K` of these keys.  The output type is `{ [P in K]: string }[]`, meaning an array of elements whose keys are `K` and whose values are `string`s.

I used some type assertions in the implementation to prevent errors (such as `as K[]` and `as {[P in K]: string}`) which means I've taken it upon myself to guarantee type safety.  I've attempted to do that by having the implementation throw errors if the keys don't match or if a line is missing an entry.  The only way this check is possible is because, at runtime, the `keys` array of type `K[]` exists (while `K` itself only exists at design time).

Anyway, let's test it out with a dummy file system:

```
const fs = {
    readFileSync(path: string, encoding: string) {
        switch (path) {
            case "badFile":
                return "bar\tbaz\nabc\nghi\tjkl"
            default:
                return "bar\tbaz\nabc\tdef\nghi\tjkl";
        }
    }
}
```

First for the happy cases:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
    baz: string;
}
const objects: Foo[] = parseTsv("somePath", "bar", "baz");
console.log(objects);
//  [{ "bar": "abc", "baz": "def" }, { "bar": "ghi", "baz": "jkl" }] 
objects.map(x => x.bar.toUpperCase())
```

That works because there are `"bar"` and `"baz"` keys in the TSV.  You can be somewhat confident that any operation you perform assuming `objects` is of type `Foo[]` will work. Now for the sad cases:

```
interface Other {
    other: string;
    key: string;
}
try {
    const others = parseTsv("somePath", "other", "key"); // RUNTIME ERROR!
    // const others: {other: string; key: string; }[]
    others.map(x => x.other.toUpperCase())
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // TSV file is missing expected header named "other" in line 1
}

try {
    const oops: Foo[] = parseTsv("badFile", "bar", "baz");
    oops.map(x => x.bar.toUpperCase())
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e); // TSV file is missing expected value for "baz" in line 2
}
```

Those fail because the file at `"somePath"` does not have `"other"` and `"key"` headers, and because the file at `"badFile"` is bad, both of which are caught at runtime.  The `others.map()` and `oops.map()` lines are never reached.  There's no problem assuming that `others` is of type `Other[]` and that `oops` is of type `Foo[]`, since the only way for that code to run would be is if those constraints were met.  So it's reasonably type safe.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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-UtQ0wo3GkysAEkhAtCLQiHACFB6K7cAQVawQHhYJHuVVeRcubdxCr0WASIgAEoEUB4EjXZIEeggcGrMTyYR3B6hnBPC4vN48IOkn5-LYR8BMl8uQQOVCAcag6EYFgXzfAwxAAci8KA4AADjg1sGX-WAqEEcYuRfOUJmwqBmDgiI0OLVRl0ICB8kKf4kxgYEKNwZdQCob1IC5bCwHGAEAAYgQI1giJI4JyKfZk8D0GhYAoLkAEYOhgOTrhgbjxjlGhhC4JSKAAaj0pErTMTCYBAWxEi5VAehhRA5noJSAHpHJgRIvCZdyrHsiTKNM4AfEIMAoHUricIgAEKEEwitBzYIix83BZSk5gZNcrk+KUyzVLYjjyy0oQdNcgyjLdNRzMSAEcpGSAAUSIEgS5fy8EC4KcNqoFmNMcMSmo2i5VYdzOGYcr0LcbrSgncp8HGWjiwGLtlxTNMNwAaS3Hc90-GQHmg8D32pYQxDlY7z3oVkYBW4Fv2nHBl0AlBgNA8hwIYJhHmePbYJgBCkNQ0bbtM9TEBQfDouI0iwHEwkqJmgpeFQRjRWUvwVqBA6hBgHoGKY0FwWYABCIHNIkArDGm7xfGmmiCmLViQHY6rgbUsL+Ki4SYtIqA0Nsi6ccJJK9GXU6zPBU6IBKtwwT0fGqsgOVBF2LxsggZhTvNOFODwEB1E9AgdftZqF2YBKcGsVZaAANXgcDlMQEYKAgCAZC3I1gHREgYE4YhsiknsPcCaxrBgPSTZgYW9JsAPkeZniYHk9JjJgf7Me6AWUonZSFN0mBVKJ-LCv0wybrUZdyqsmzYQRgEkcEC60a24RMc6mBWICiRWtjlAgYitmROsOLk9UNPUsslAMrS7L6dy4ntM4TLiuLjCjjDi9Gqnxn2ub3zl4uIgqEatugvUzfQ6lx56CNK8YF3-f8aQFAhWDYRJQ1rWdZ4-XDbwY3E-cM3LetjQW2MB7aO2drOV27tr57wRJJGAAcg4h1-m4cOkcg61xCogvQckI7yQUKHQebhyoAlOg1FATUWrHzqs3caqheoFH6oNYaFlk7jTKJTehUByRdhtJiIg2IXS-ndFUdGxZAx3jJFgAYpcLJHieGyRMZCVynFTJcHMwoxQSjEJUPA1htFhHipgRk9MCCaRAEIZhiQ5Hi3JM5HAAIEY6OcDYKIwA9H+FqM46wTQg49DEI4gIXi4gUHcZUUIXiUhpExg1LA5VrEVmVGqX4NYtRVB1PqQ0xoLAEBbJaXhdoYAAHkuAYmLosL2eBRHdFOlUwYWBPhTiES3Uy5SMRMyWmo3MmjCzaNabo7Rp0iwwDsfuPUAA5VY-YACy9oYD2n3PuQp+58bdD6eWRUiTqyaj6ekg0Ro8AmhyeabodjS4lNOPDPpoiV70GuVjEEgwW4cB0HoRExdjE0DMRYxETkXLmytnAG2DsQEOydo3CBcimye29qUv2Ng+noL8CFeSUjLQNPeS0kArBzrsgYh0i4OZ7DPScPoqooSDHJzxNihJVZkm1jSbqPZWTTTHMeeYbQuhmBvKaR80xVBzFcqlMMv5ADAVAOBaAsFGMIVuyhTfWBAswmIpjlYAATKizAQA)